# How can we get as close as we want to $\ln (2)$ with the series below?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please explain how we can get as close as we want to $\ln(2)$ by using

$$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + ... + \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)}$$

Comment: See the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), especially the section on [the error of the partial sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Proof_of_partial_sum_error_bound).

Comment: We can get as close as we want by calculating more and more terms of this series. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series)

Comment: Or you might want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples) link.

Comment: In fact, you can get as close as you want to any other value (even infinity) just by changing the order in which you perform the sums https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! Its all cleared up. Just a question tho, how come I am being downvoted? I don't think I broke any posting rules and I am pretty sure this question isn't a repeat

Comment: Don't bother about downvoting. There are people that faced to a little (understandable) awkwardness in a question forget that they have been students before...  Besides, if you are looking for a faster convergent series for computing any value ln(a), consider the series $(1/2)ln((1+x)/(1-x))=x+x^3/3+x^5/5+x^7/7+...$. For example, taking x=1/3 in this series, one obtains easily $(1/2)ln(4)=ln(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from an integral definition of $\log(2)$, for instance. We have:
$$ \log(2) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
together with:
$$ 0\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1}\tag{2} $$
hence the difference between:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-(-1)^n x^n}{1+x}\,dx = 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\ldots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\tag{3} $$
and $\log(2)$ is at most $\frac{1}{n+1}$ in absolute value.